# Flex: detecting when text does and doesn't fit in `mxTextArea`

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex3

My bottom-line problem is that I need the `TextArea` to be up to 2 lines long to accommodate large amounts of text and then shrink to 1 line when 2 aren't necessary. The answer should be obvious, right?

```
private function OnScroll(evt:ScrollEvent):void {
  if (!isNaN(evt.position)) DoWhatNeedsDoneWhenAScrollAppears();
}
```

...

```
<mx:TextArea scroll="OnScroll(event)" />
```

This way, a scroll bar should appear when there's more text than can be fit in the control, and I know I need 2 lines. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when I assign text to the `text` member, and I don't see any way to detect hidden text.
I've also tried:

```
public override function set text(s:String):void {
    super.text = s;
    invalidateSize();
    invalidateDisplayList();
    invalidateProperties();
}
```

Of course, even if I solved this problem, I'm left w/the problem of knowing when the shrink the line, and I wouldn't know that unless the text is an empty string.

I'm using the Flex 3.5 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far is to use `measureText()`. Whenever text is changed (by overriding the `text` set or by handing the `change` event) I see if `measuredText()` indicates that the string is wider than the control, in which case I make the `TextArea` twice as high. At least I *tried* that, until I saw just how unreliable `measureText()` is for that sort of thing. Now I double the height if `measureText()` indicates that the text is 95% of the control's width. And, it's still unreliable, but the lesser or 2 evils.